# Как в Xcode прочесть нажатие клавиши без остановки программы?

Tags: c++, xcode, input

Нужно прочесть нажатие клавиши в цикле. Пробовал примерно так:

```
while(true){
     if(std::getchar() == 's') // не работает
     ...

     char c;
     std::cin>>c// не работает
     if(c=='s')
     ...
}
```

Эти варианты требуют нажатия клавиши Enter по окончанию ввода.

Доп потоков для считывания ввода создавать не нужно. Так же нужно чтобы считывание клавиши не требовало подтверждения нажатия Enter. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: вам нужен нубуферезированный ввод, если я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Наверно, мне нужно просто определить была нажата определенная клавиша или нет. Есть пример того как можно это сделать?

Comment: для этого вам нужно не IDE указать, а операционку. Так как в разных операционках для этого используются разные хэдэры и функции, так как нубуферезированный ввод не стандартизирован

Comment: Можете показать где что указывать? Я в Xcode совсем 0, даже нануглить ничего не могу толкового, везде ObjectiveC нахожу

Comment: Xcode - IDE, тобишь среда разработки. А я спрашиваю: какая у вас операционная система?

Comment: OSX HighSierra v10.13.6, так я и хотел узнать что подкрутить в среде чтобы она считывала поток ввода с операционки.

Comment: Казалось бы, при чём тут XCode?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int mygetch()
{
    struct termios oldt,
    newt;
    int ch;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt );
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt );
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt );
    return ch;
}
```

Comment: Это пробовал. Что странно, mygetch вроде и работает, но только несколько раз. Через сколь-ко то считываний mygetch начинает постоянно срабатывать.

Comment: не замечал такого, у меня работает исправно, на linux

Comment: Добавте к ответу какие хэдэры подключали.